# Running Flask dev server in Python 3.6 raises ImportError for SocketServer and ForkingMixIn

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug, python-3.6

I am trying to run a basic Flask app using Python 3.6.  However, I get an `ImportError: cannot import name 'ForkingMixIn'`.  I don't get this error when running with Python 2.7 or 3.5.  How can I run Flask with Python 3.6?

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello, World!"
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 65, in <module>
    from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn, ForkingMixIn
ImportError: No module named 'SocketServer'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\fsk.py", line 9, in <module>
    app.run()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 828, in run
    from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 68, in <module>
    from socketserver import ThreadingMixIn, ForkingMixIn
ImportError: cannot import name 'ForkingMixIn'
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is fixed as of Werkzeug 0.11.15. Make sure you have installed the latest version of Werkzeug. `pip install -U werkzeug`.

---

This is a known issue that was [reported to Werkzeug](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/pull/999) in anticipation of Python 3.6.  Until that or another patch is merged and released, Werkzeug's dev server will not run on Python 3.6.

> Check if OS can fork before importing `ForkingMixIn` since Python 3.6 will no longer define that when it is not available on the operating system ([python/cpython@aadff9b](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/aadff9bea61a2fc9f4cf0f213f0ee50fc54d6574)) and `ImportError: cannot import name 'ForkingMixIn'` will occur.

In the mean time, you can run your app with an external WSGI server such as Gunicorn.

```
pip install gunicorn
gunicorn my_app:app
```

You can wrap your app in the [debug middleware](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/debug/#werkzeug.debug.DebuggedApplication) if you need the in-page debugger (as long as you only run Gunicorn with one worker).